# How to get the output of curl

Tags: ruby

I am using the system curl as I cannot get the ruby curl to work. How do I get the output of the curl into my ruby variable? the example below shows that the variable did not get the output of the curl

```
url1="\"https://ca.yahoo.com/\""
a=Kernel.system "curl #{url1}"
irb(main):026:0> a
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Kernel#system Doesn't Capture Standard Output

[Kernel#system](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) only returns true, false or nil, so you can't capture command output that way. Instead, use [Kernel#`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60) (or its alternative `%x{}` syntax) to capture standard output. For example:

```rb
url    = 'https://ca.yahoo.com/'
output = %x(curl "#{url}")
```

For more complex things, you may also want to look at the [Open3 module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) from the Ruby Standard Library. It has various methods for supporting pipelines, and different ways to treat standard input, standard output, and standard error separately when necessary.